# I ran a command that was supposed to show me the data about my object detection ai but i get an error that i can't solve

Tags: python, data-science, object-detection, python-unicode

basically i have this command:

```
python Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet\pipeline.config --checkpoint_dir=Tensorflow\workspace\models\my_ssd_mobnet
```

and the problem is that i get a unicode error which i have never had before here is the error in the image

[this is the full error i got when running the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwAYH.png)

to clarify things i ran this commmand on the windows command prompt using python.

to try and fix it, i first searched on the internet and found about 2 results that could maybe apply but didnt end up working since it wasnt in the command prompt and other than that well i asked in a discord but no body seems to have the answer either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode